# error Can't add "react-navigation": invalid package version undefined when run yarn

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to install the project packages with the command "yarn " in MacBook Pro

OS : macOS Mojave version 10.14.5
"react-native": "0.60.5",
"react": "16.8.6",
"react-navigation": "3.11.0",

yarn version 1.22.0

Please find the attached images for the reference.

Screenshot 2020-02-26 at 4 10 40 PM

and I have another Dell laptop (Windows) there I could install the dependencies with the command "yarn"

I need to install packages with the command "yarn" or "yarn install"

[image]

Comment: Please show your packge.json dependencies specially react-navigation

Comment: run separately `yarn add react-navigation`

Comment: Agree with @Jai alternatively use npm i react-navigation 
Error seems like version mismatch, please correct the version

Comment: @JuhilSomaiya and add a flag `--save` too.

Answer (score 4):

In the project root directory you can run this command to add dependencies:

```
yarn add react react-native react-navigation
```

This will add the latest available versions or you can specify the latest version to the `package.json` dependencies entries:

```
dependencies: {
    .....
    "react-navigation":"^4.0.0"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete any entry that is available in your `package.json` that starts with react-navigation and then run

```
yarn add react-navigation
```

or take a valid react-navigation version for example:

`"react-navigation": "^4.0.10",`

place that inside your `package.json` under dependencies and run `npm install`